# Find the value of $\frac{x^5+y^5+z^5-1}{xyz}.$

Tags: contest-math

Let $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $xy+yz+zx=0$ and $xyz \neq 0.$ Find the value of $\frac{x^5+y^5+z^5-1}{xyz}.$

=$...\frac{(x+y+z)^5+5xyz(x+y+z)^2−1}{xyz}$
so for x+y+z=1 we have 5. Is it possible to find another value?

Comment: that equal you wrote is comparing which quantities exactly?

Comment: This from the problem.

Comment: If $x+y+z=1$ is not a requirement, then there are tons of other possibilities. For example, the expression will be $-\frac{31}{16}$ when $x=1,y=1,z=-\frac 1 2$.

Comment: "Is it possible to find another value?" Yes. Choose arbitrary values for $x$ and $y$. Solve for $z$. Substitute these into your expression and will you get another value.

Comment: Ok, thanks I see that.